# How to run Photoviewer.dll in command line

Tags: .net, windows-7, 64-bit, tiff, photoviewer

When I run the following code below in a command prompt (as administrator):

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" "C:\00012.tif"
```

it produces error as shown below :

> "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an associated in the Default Programs control panel."

Both `.tif` and `.tiff` are associated in the Default programs control panel.

I am trying to call this from a .net windows app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> rundll32 "C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll" "C:\00012.tif"

For running a dll, there is `rundll32`.

Comment: Nothing is opened after running this on Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, nothing happens on Windows 10! What's wrong?

Comment: I'd say that's unsurprising considering there have been 10 years of changes to Windows since this answer was written :)

Answer (score 37):

**Windows 7**

```
rundll32 "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen path_to_image
```

- path_to_image must *not* be quoted!

Comment: Just as a side note to Laerne's point, `path_to_image` must be the full path to the file, NOT the relative path. Made this mistake a few times myself.

Comment: path_to_image must NOT be quoted!

Comment: Is there a way to then start a diaporama ?

Comment: How to use this with a file that has space in it, if I cannot use quotes?

Comment: Is there a place where rundll32-accessible functions are listed for this? Maybe there are other things available besides ImageViewer_Fullscreen?

Comment: @GuilhermeMussi I know that was an old question, but you simply omit the quotes. Works just fine.

Answer (score 13):

It's not necessary to run PhotoViewer directly, let explorer do the work for you. As a bonus, it works with relative paths as far as I can tell.

```
C:\Users\alphaniner> explorer Documents\test.png
```

Comment: The OP asks specifically how to call PhotoViewer.

Comment: Note that this is not guaranteed to run PhotoViewer, it runs whatever program you have associated with the .png extension.

Answer (score 0):

By definition this answers the ops question but it may not be what he wants.

```
"C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe" "C:\somepic.png"
```