# How to use Windows Photo Viewer to open an image Using Java?

Tags: java, windows

I want to view a photo using Windows Photo Viewer ... I'm using `ProcessBuilder` to do that, but the compiler does not accept this .
I tried typing `mspaint` instead of `windowsphotoviewer` and it worked.
So how can i do that ? here is the line of code i tried:

```
Process photo = new ProcessBuilder("mspaint","Capture.PNG").start();
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: It could be a matter of launching a DLL, see this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190271/how-to-run-photoviewer-dll-in-command-line

Comment: "The compiler does not accept this" - please add the exact error message from the compiler.

Comment: @Robin
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "windowsphotoviewer": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
`
Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Berger thanks for your help

Comment: @toubou Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine for mspaint.

```
String path = "D:\\imgfolder\\img.jpg";
String expr = "mspaint " + path;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(expr);
```

This should work fine for Windows photo viewer

```
String path = "D:\\imgfolder\\img.jpg";
String expr = "rundll32 \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen " + path;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(expr);
```